# Remove near-duplicate elements in Python list while preserving variables

Tags: python, list

I have a list that contains near-duplicate elements, with the exception of a number that identifies the element. I want to remove all duplicates while preserving the number of the first element containing a duplicate.

For example, I want to replace `l` with `lnew`:

```
l = ['iter1apple','iter2banana','iter3carrot','iter4apple','iter5orange','iter6banana','iter7mango']

lnew = ['iter1apple','iter2banana','iter3carrot','iter5orange','iter7mango']
```

I'm guessing this has something to do with splitting the number from the rest of the list element, converting the list to set and using `defaultdict` with the elements from the split, but I can't figure out how.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: So how did you decide to remove `iter4apple` and `iter6banana`? The general solution would be something like `lnew = [elem for elem in l if elem not in discardable]` where `discardable` is a set of the ones you want removed.

Comment: @hughdbrown: `discardable` is not predefined. I'm trying to determine what constitutes as discardable based on the element position and whether or not it is a duplicate of an element with a lower `iter` number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood you correctly, you want to discard the items which end in one element that is already contained in the list. In that case, you can use a regular expression and a list to track the elements that have been used:

```
import re

l = ['iter1apple', 'iter2banana', 'iter3carrot', 'iter4apple', 'iter5orange', 'iter6banana', 'iter7mango']
duplicates = []
lnew = []
for item in l:
    match = re.match("^iter\d+(\w+)$", item)
    if match and not match.group(1) in duplicates:
        duplicates.append(match.group(1))
        lnew.append(item)

# lnew = ['iter1apple','iter2banana','iter3carrot','iter5orange','iter7mango']
```